# Can't find c++ libraries on unix

Tags: c++, unix

I've written a simple c++ program, test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s;
  cin >> s;
  cout << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does runnning `gcc test.cpp -o mytest` give me these errors, and more?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
      _main in cc8rGYVq.o
  "std::cin", referenced from:
      _main in cc8rGYVq.o
```

Comment: What Unix system are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the executable named `gcc` to compile and link C++ programs; you must use `g++`. Not only does it select the appropriate compiler options, it also links with the right libraries for your language (which is the problem you're having here.)

Comment: Well, you *could* use gcc command but then you have to explicitly link the c++ runtime with -lstdc++.

Answer (score 2):

"gcc" command compiles C code, in order to compile C++ code you should use "g++"

Comment: Which is kinda crappy, because `gcc` was meant to be a front-end, or driver, for underlying toolchain binaries. And it *should* recognize that it is about to compile C++ source by looking at the file extension (`.cc`, `.cpp`, `.cxx` etc. for C++). It can do it for other languages, so why couldn't it deal with C/C++ issue too? :P